# Auto Layout Programmatically with Scroll View Error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am trying to have add a view inside a paging-scrollView inside of a ViewController, and I am having a lot of Auto Layout problems (all of this code is programatic, non-Storyboard).

The first set of constraints work properly, but the second set (`sv` and `firstView`) cause the following error: `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated, code below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()

    sv.backgroundColor = .redColor()
    view.addSubview(sv)

    sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[sv]|", options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["sv": sv]))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[sv]|", options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["sv": sv]))
    sv.pagingEnabled = true

    let firstView = UIView()
    firstView.backgroundColor = .greenColor()
    sv.addSubview(firstView)
    firstView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sv.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[f]|", options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["fv": firstView]))
    sv.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[fv]|", options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["fv": firstView]))
}
```

Comment: You have "[f]" instead of "[fv]" in one of your visual formats

Comment: wow, that was it! Thanks so much. Amazing that the debugging can't tell me that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dan pointed out, there is a typo in the string in the visual format. I'll leave this post up in case anyone happens to run into a similar issue. The take-away:

`terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException` with Auto Layout might be caused by typos in the visual strings.